# Error trying to transfer data from variable between storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, variables, storyboard, segue

I have a game where I store the value of the high score of a player as "highScore", in the first view controllers.

What I want to do is to try to transfer this variable data, to the second view controller.

I entered in the following code in the first view controller's storyboard.

Btw, highscore2, is the variable that I delcared in the second view controller, to store the data from the first highscore variable.:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender:AnyObject!)
{
           if (segue.identifier == "segueTest")
            {
                var svc = segue!.destinationViewController as! viewTwo;

                svc.highScore2 = "High Score \(highScore)"

            }
 }
```

Now here is the code in my second view controller (viewTwo):

```
class viewTwo: UIViewController
{



    @IBOutlet var highScoretwolbl: UILabel!

    var highScore2:String!



    override func viewDidLoad() {
            highScoretwolbl.text = highScore2
    }
}
```

For some reason, the code compiles, but the high score is not displayed, and is "nil".

Comment: Which kind of segue are you using? show(push), show detail(replace), present modally, popover? if it's `show`, then it should work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in other answers, viewDidLoad only gets fired once. Since you
are using a forced unwrapped string, it is initially nil. It (highScore2) won't get a value until you set it which happens **after** viewDidLoad. Add some print statements so you can see the sequence of events.

Your best option is to use viewWillAppear. This will get fired every time
your view appears. This is what you want.

You don't need to use a force unwrapped variable. Just make a string a
make it empty initially.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender:AnyObject?)
{
   if segue.identifier == "segueTest"
   {
        if let svc = segue.destinationViewController as? viewTwo {
            print("setting score in prepareForSegue")
            svc.highScore2 = "High Score \(highScore)"
        }
        else {
            print("something bad happened")
        }
    }
}


class viewTwo: UIViewController
{


    @IBOutlet var highScoretwolbl: UILabel!

    // The following uses forced upwrapping which means it could be nil
    // if you never set it and your app will crash.
    // var highScore2: String!
    // Instead, do this:
    var highScore2: String = ""

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        // putting this here will ensure that every time the screen
        // is shown, the label will get set from the string.
        highScoretwolbl.text = highScore2
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of viewWillAppear, did u mean viewDidLoad? It says that it can't override the function, because there is no function named viewWillAppear to override.

Comment: My Bad, i forgot to add the parameter to the function. But for some reason, it still shows me a blank text field

Comment: This is the correct approach. You are going to have to debug this. Add print statements along the way to see what values are being passed and received. Here's a simple example that works : https://github.com/ryantxr/legendary-potato

Comment: It looks like the method signature is wrong. You have this: `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue!, sender:AnyObject!)`.  This is what it should be: `prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)`

Answer (score 1):

Avoid forced unwrapping.

```
if let svc = segue.destinationViewController as? viewTwo{
    svc.highScore2 = "High Score \(highScore)"
}
```

Then put in a breakpoint and make sure you got to all of these lines.

Answer (score 0):

If I recall correctly, the `viewDidLoad` method is called only once when the view controller is first initialized. So you are setting the `highScoretwolbl` variable before `highScore2` actually has any data, this is why it is nil.

I would recommend setting the text inside `viewWillAppear` so it updates every time the segue happens.

So something like

```
 override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)
    highScoretwolbl.text = highScore2
}
```

Here is a reference to the lifecycle of all the methods of a view controller. [View controller lifecycle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eYCHy.jpg)

Comment: For some reason, it still shows me a blank text field